# Laravel Exception when trying to Login

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

im tring to log in to my application but i just can't. After reading a lot of useless solutions i thought of asking.
Im using Laravel 5.4 with Passport, i have run all the migrations successfully, composer update, and php artisan passport:client. No problems, but when i try to log in i get:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(1/1) Exception
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST http://localhost/oauth/token` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found (truncated...)
in /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
Stack trace:
#0 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#2 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#3 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#4 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true)
#5 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(223): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#6 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(267): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#7 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(225): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#8 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#9 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(131): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#10 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(89): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('post', 'http://localhos...', Array)
#11 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/LoginController.php(24): GuzzleHttp\Client->__call('post', Array)
#12 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\LoginController->postLogin(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('postLogin', Array)
#15 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\LoginController), 'postLogin')
#16 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#17 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(572): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#18 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), '60', '1')
#24 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(574): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#27 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(533): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(511): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#42 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/server.php(21): require_once('/media/elver/14...')
#45 {main}
in LoginController.php (line 30)
at LoginController->postLogin(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(LoginController), 'postLogin'), array(object(Request)))
in Controller.php (line 55)
at Controller->callAction('postLogin', array(object(Request)))
in ControllerDispatcher.php (line 44)
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(LoginController), 'postLogin')
in Route.php (line 203)
at Route->runController()
in Route.php (line 160)
at Route->run()
in Router.php (line 572)
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in SubstituteBindings.php (line 41)
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ThrottleRequests.php (line 49)
at ThrottleRequests->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), '60', '1')
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Router.php (line 574)
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request))
in Router.php (line 533)
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 511)
at Router->dispatch(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 176)
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 30)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in TransformsRequest.php (line 30)
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in ValidatePostSize.php (line 27)
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php (line 46)
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
in Pipeline.php (line 148)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 53)
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
in Pipeline.php (line 102)
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure))
in Kernel.php (line 151)
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request))
in Kernel.php (line 116)
at Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in index.php (line 53)
at require_once('/media/elver/14CCAC30CCAC0DD4/Laburo/Buckhamduffy/mycleaner/public/index.php')
in server.php (line 21)
```

The line where it throws the exception is from this controller:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

    try {
        $oauth_response = $http->post(env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID'),
                'client_secret' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_SECRET'),
                'username' => $request->get('email'),
                'password' => $request->get('password'),
                'scope' => '*'
            ],
        ]);

        $response = json_decode((string) $oauth_response->getBody(), true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e);
        return response('', 500);
    }

    return response($response);
```

php artisan route:list

```
    | Domain | Method    | URI                                                            | Name               | Action                                                                     | Middleware         |
    +--------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
...
              | api                |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/login/refresh                                           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\LoginController@postLoginRefresh               | api                |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/logout                                                  |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\LoginController@postLogout                     | api,auth:api       |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/notes                                                   |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\NotesController@postCreate                     | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/notes/{id}                                              |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\NotesController@postEdit                       | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/notes/{id}                                              |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\NotesController@getNote                        | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | DELETE    | api/v1/notes/{id}                                              |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\NotesController@deleteNote                     | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | PUT       | api/v1/public/services/{id}                                    |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@putEdit                     | api                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/services                                                |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@getIndex                    | api,auth:api       |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/services                                                |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@postCreate                  | api,auth:api       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/services/{id}                                           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@getService                  | api,auth:api       |
    |        | DELETE    | api/v1/services/{id}                                           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@delete                      | api,auth:api       |
    |        | PUT       | api/v1/services/{id}                                           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@putEdit                     | api,auth:api       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/services/{id}/cleaners                                  |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@getServiceCleaners          | api,auth:api       |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/services/{id}/cleaners/attach                           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@postAttachCleaner           | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/services/{id}/cleaners/match                            |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@getMatchingCleaners         | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | PUT       | api/v1/services/{id}/confirm                                   |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@putConfirmService           | api,auth:api       |
    |        | PUT       | api/v1/services/{id}/owner                                     |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@putUpdateOwner              | api,auth:api       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/services/{id}/teams                                     |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@getServiceTeams             | api,auth:api       |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/services/{id}/teams/attach                              |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\ServicesController@postAttachTeam              | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/signup/cleaner                                          |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\SignupController@postCleaner                   | api                |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/signup/client                                           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\SignupController@postClient                    | api                |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/staffs                                                  |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Users\StaffsController@postCreate              | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/staffs                                                  |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Users\StaffsController@getIndex                | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | DELETE    | api/v1/staffs/{id}                                             |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Users\StaffsController@destroy                 | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/staffs/{id}                                             |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Users\StaffsController@postEdit                | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/staffs/{id}                                             |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Users\StaffsController@getShow                 | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | PUT       | api/v1/staffs/{id}/restore                                     |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Users\UsersController@restore                  | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/suburbs                                                 |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Support\SuburbsController@getIndex             | api                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/timezones                                               |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Support\TimezoneController@getIndex            | api                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/user                                                    |                    | Closure                                                                    | api,auth:api       |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/user/{id}/notes                                         |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\NotesController@getNotes                       | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/users/{user_id}/activities                              |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Users\ActivitiesController@getActivities       | api,auth:api,admin |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/users/{user_id}/stripe/customer                         |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\StripeController@createCustomer                | api                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/users/{user_id}/stripe/customer                         |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\StripeController@getCustomer                   | api                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/v1/users/{user_id}/stripe/customer/cards                   |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\StripeController@getCustomerCards              | api                |
    |        | POST      | api/v1/users/{user_id}/stripe/customer/cards                   |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\StripeController@addCustomerCard               | api                |
    |        | DELETE    | api/v1/users/{user_id}/stripe/customer/cards/{card_id}         |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\StripeController@deleteCustomerCard            | api                |
    |        | PUT       | api/v1/users/{user_id}/stripe/customer/cards/{card_id}/default |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\StripeController@setDefaultCard                | api                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | book                                                           |                    | Closure                                                                    | web                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | checkout                                                       |                    | Closure                                                                    | web                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | cleaner                                                        |                    | Closure                                                                    | web                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | cleaner/{any}                                                  |                    | Closure                                                                    | web                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | invitations/accept/{token}                                     | invitations.accept | App\Http\Controllers\Users\InvitationsController@getAccept                 | web                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | login                                                          |                    | Closure                                                                    | web                |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/authorize                                                |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize       | web,auth           |
    |        | POST      | oauth/authorize                                                |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController@approve  | web,auth           |
    |        | DELETE    | oauth/authorize                                                |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\DenyAuthorizationController@deny        | web,auth           |
    |        | POST      | oauth/clients                                                  |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@store                  | web,auth           |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/clients                                                  |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@forUser                | web,auth           |
    |        | PUT       | oauth/clients/{client_id}                                      |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@update                 | web,auth           |
    |        | DELETE    | oauth/clients/{client_id}                                      |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@destroy                | web,auth           |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/personal-access-tokens                                   |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@forUser   | web,auth           |
    |        | POST      | oauth/personal-access-tokens                                   |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@store     | web,auth           |
    |        | DELETE    | oauth/personal-access-tokens/{token_id}                        |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@destroy   | web,auth           |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/scopes                                                   |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ScopeController@all                     | web,auth           |
    |        | POST      | oauth/token                                                    |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | throttle           |
    |        | POST      | oauth/token/refresh                                            |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web,auth           |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | oauth/tokens                                                   |                    | \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web,auth           |
    |        | DELETE    | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                                        ...
```

Please help!

Comment: Can we see your routes.php file?

Comment: @suecarmol i added  `php artisan route:list` output!

Comment: Make sure that `env('APP_URL')` is indeed pointing to the correct url. In your case is the main site at `http://localhost`? Confirm it is not something like `http://localhost:8080`.